# How to set y axis value in vertical bar chart using chart JS

Tags: javascript, css, charts, chart.js

In this vertical bar chart there are positive, negative value in y axis in this chart.

I want to use positive integers up and down based on the zero value.

I'm using version 4.2.1

what should I do ??

vertical chart example

[image: 1]

```
    var MONTHS = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var barChartData = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Dataset 1",
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [
            10,
            20,
            30,
            40,
            50
          ],
        },
        {
          label: "Dataset 2",
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [
            -100,
            -200,
            -300,
            -400,
            -500
          ],
        },
      ],
    };

    var ctx = bloodPressureChart;
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: barChartData,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: "top",
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Chart.js Bar Chart",
        },
      },
    });
```

this is my code using chart JS.

my code chart

[image: 2]

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand which way you want to modify your chart. The only differences I see between the "vertical chart example" image and "my code chart" image is that both datasets have the same color and the negative values have larger amplitudes than the negative ones. Otherwise, the positive value bars go up from zero and the negative ones go down in both images. Do you want the zero line to be in the middle? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Hello ! Thanks to comment my question.

I want to change value in blue box to positive value.

y aixs value = 100 80 60 40 20 0 20 40 60 80 100

like this.

I want both sides to be positive based on zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change just the text of the y axis labels, they can be changed completely by setting the function `options.scales.y.ticks.callback`, see the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) and [API reference](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/TickOptions.html#callback) for details. In your case, to make negative values read positive you may use:

```
callback: function(val){
    return this.getLabelForValue(Math.abs(val));
}
```

or

```
callback: function(val){
    return this.getLabelForValue(val).replace(/^-/, '');
}
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1');
var MONTHS = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
];

var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Dataset 1",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [
                10,
                20,
                30,
                40,
                50
            ],
        },
        {
            label: "Dataset 2",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [
                -100,
                -200,
                -300,
                -400,
                -500
            ],
        },
    ],
};

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: "top",
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Chart.js Bar Chart",
        },
        scales:{
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(val){
                        return this.getLabelForValue(Math.abs(val));
                        // or: //return this.getLabelForValue(val).replace(/^-/, '');
                    },
                }
            }
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart1" style="height:500px"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```